# Passing parsed array to main activity

Tags: android, arrays, json

Hello im new in android and thats my problem.
i have one activity where i have method to load Json file
and a method where i parse that file to my array object.
the name of the object[class with constracter] is "hotelSummary"

thats my parsing method:

public HotelSummary[] parseJson() {

```
    String s = loadJSONFromAsset();

    HotelSummary closeHotelsArray[] = {};


    try {

        JSONObject rootJSON = new JSONObject(s);

        JSONArray hotelsJSON = rootJSON.getJSONObject("HotelListResponse").getJSONObject("HotelList").getJSONArray("HotelSummary");

        closeHotelsArray = new HotelSummary[hotelsJSON.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < closeHotelsArray.length; i++) {


            JSONObject jsonObject = hotelsJSON.getJSONObject(i);

            HotelSummary hs = new HotelSummary();
            hs.address1 = jsonObject.getString("address1");
            hs.airportCode = jsonObject.getString("airportCode");
            hs.hotelId = jsonObject.getInt("hotelId");
            hs.confidenceRating = jsonObject.getInt("confidenceRating");
            hs.hotelRating = jsonObject.getInt("hotelRating");
            hs.lowRate = jsonObject.getInt("lowRate");
            hs.name = jsonObject.getString("name");
            hs.order = jsonObject.getInt("order");
            hs.proximityDistance = jsonObject.getDouble("proximityDistance");
            hs.proximityUnit = jsonObject.getString("proximityUnit");
            hs.thumbNailUrl = jsonObject.getString("thumbNailUrl");

            closeHotelsArray[i]= hs;

        }

    }catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return closeHotelsArray;

}
```

ass you can see it returns me array

now i wanna pass that array to my main activity 
to connect it to my listview
how can i pass the array?.

thanks for the help
and sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 0):

You can place this method in your mainActivity itself and then calling it will return the required array. Is there any restriction because of which you cannot place it in the main activity?

Comment: i prefer keep my main activity "clean" and do this stuff in other class and then just pass the ready array to display it

Comment: Then you can make this method static so that it can be accessed directly from other activities. That would be the simplest approach!

Comment: The structure could be like this : `public class myParsingClass{ public static HotelSummary[] parseJson() { //your parsing method here } }`  you can then call it from your main activity as `HotelSummary[] myHotelSummary =  myParsingClass.parseJson();`